# Rotating a plane on a point

Tags: java, rotation, geometry, plane

I have a Java class that creates a virtual screen (let's call it a map) that can be translated, resized, and rotated. 
When I rotate it, however, it only rotates it around (0, 0). 
To transform the point to the screen you first rotate it, then resize it, then translate it.

```
private double dx; //offset in x and y
private double dy;
private double t; //rotation (radians)
private double sx; //scale of x and y
private double sy;
public double[] toScreen(double x, double y) //takes (x, y) on the map and gives (x1, y1) for the screen 
{
    double[] xy = {x, y};
    if(t != 0)
    {
        double distance = Math.hypot(xy[0], xy[1]);
        double theta = Math.atan2(xy[1], xy[0]) + t;
        xy[0] = Math.cos(theta)*distance;
        xy[1] = Math.sin(theta)*distance;
    }
    xy[0] *= sx;
    xy[1] *= sy;

    xy[0] += dx;
    xy[1] += dy;
    return xy;
}
```

to set the rotation or change it, you manipulate the variable `t`, but it rotates on (0, 0). 
If I make a method that takes in (x, y) to rotate around like `public void changeRotation(double t, double x, double y)`. 
I want (x, y) to be map coordinates. What would the method look like and can you explain what it does?

Comment: Welcome to SO. "To transform the point to the screen you first rotate it, then resize it, then translate it." Is it essential information to answer your question ? If not it may be confusing, consider removing it.

Comment: If I understand your question right, you have a method that calculates a rotation of a point `x,y` , around `0,0` and you ask how to calculate the point's rotation about an arbitrary point `x1,y1`. Is that the question ?

Comment: not really, just change the offset of the map (dx, dy) to make it rotate about a pivot

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. The requested method signature : `void changeRotation(double t, double x, double y)` only adds `t` as a parameter to the method.  I thought you wanted `double  rotate(double t, double[] point, double[] center)` .  A numeric example could clarify it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly this is what you need :

```
/**
 * @param point  point (x,y) of the coordinates to be rotated
 * @param center point (x,y) of the center (pivot) coordinates
 * @param angle in radians
 * @return point (x,y) of the new (translated) coordinates 
 */
static Point2D.Double rotateAPoint(Point2D.Double point, Point2D.Double center, double angle){

    double newX = center.x + Math.cos(angle) * (point.x - center.x) -
                                        Math.sin(angle) * (point.y-center.y) ;
    double newY = center.y + Math.sin(angle) * (point.x - center.x) +
                                        Math.cos(angle) * (point.y - center.y) ;
    return new Point2D.Double(newX, newY);
}
```

Try with

```
Point2D.Double  point = new Point2D.Double(200,100);
Point2D.Double center = new Point2D.Double(100,100);
double angle = Math.PI/2 ; //90 degress
System.out.println(rotateAPoint(point, center, angle) );
System.out.println(rotateAPoint(point, center, -angle));
```

If you prefer to use `double[]` :

```
/**
 * @param point  (x,y) of the coordinates to be rotated
 * @param center (x,y) of the center (pivot) coordinates
 * @param angle in radians
 * @return (x,y) of the new (translated) coordinates 
 */
static double[] rotateAPoint(double[] point, double[] center, double angle){

    double newX = center[0] + Math.cos(angle) * (point[0] - center[0]) -
                                        Math.sin(angle) * (point[0]-center[0]) ;
    double newY = center[1] + Math.sin(angle) * (point[1] - center[1]) +
                                        Math.cos(angle) * (point[1] - center[1]) ;
    return new double[]{newX, newY};
}
```

Explanation about the math [here](https://academo.org/demos/rotation-about-point/)

Comment: yes! thank you. this is what I was looking for! although I have already figured it out, yours is much simpler.